# ShingleFilter in Lucene 4.6 adds words to bigrams

Tags: java, lucene

I am puzzled by the strange behavior of ShingleFilter in Lucene 4.6.   What I would like to do is extract all possible bigrams from a sentence.  So if the sentence is "this is a dog", I want "this is", "is a ", "a dog".

What I see instead is:

"this this is"

"this is is"

"is is a"

"is a a"

"a a dog"

"a dog dog"

So somehow it replicates words and makes 3-grams instead of bigrams.

Here is my Java code:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
ShingleAnalyzerWrapper shingleAnalyzer = new ShingleAnalyzerWrapper(analyzer,2,2);

String theSentence = "this is a dog";
StringReader reader = new StringReader(theSentence);
TokenStream tokenStream = shingleAnalyzer.tokenStream("content", reader);
ShingleFilter theFilter = new ShingleFilter(tokenStream);
theFilter.setOutputUnigrams(false);

CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = theFilter.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);                                                                                   
theFilter.reset();

 while (theFilter.incrementToken()) {                                                 
            System.out.println(charTermAttribute.toString());                                  
 }

 theFilter.end();
 theFilter.close();
```

Could someone please help me modify it so it actually outputs bigrams and does not replicate words?  Thank you!

Natalia

Comment: I completely do the same locally. First of all, I get only `_ dog dog`, nothing more

Comment: Very nice [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/), by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are applying *two* `ShingleFilter`s.  `ShingleAnalyzerWrapper` tacks one onto the `StandardAnalyzer`, and then you add another one explicitly.  Since the `ShingleAnalyzerWrapper` uses it's default behavior of outputing unigrams, you end up with the following tokens off of that first ShingleFilter:

- this
- this is
- is
- is a
- a
- a dog
- dog

so when the second filter comes along (this time without unigrams), it simply combines each consecutive tokens among those, leading to the result your are seeing.

So, either eliminate the `ShingleAnalyzerWrapper`, or the `ShingleFilter` added later.  For instance, this should work:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);

String theSentence = "this is a dog";
StringReader reader = new StringReader(theSentence);
TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("content", reader);
ShingleFilter theFilter = new ShingleFilter(tokenStream);
theFilter.setOutputUnigrams(false);

CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = theFilter.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
theFilter.reset();

while (theFilter.incrementToken()) {
    System.out.println(charTermAttribute.toString());
}

theFilter.end();
theFilter.close();
```

Comment: It's been a couple years but I gotta give you credit for the right answer. First upvote.  Wow.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to produce correct results, using this code

```
    String theSentence = "this is a dog";
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(theSentence);
    StandardTokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_46, reader);
    TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_46, source);
    ShingleFilter sf = new ShingleFilter(tokenStream);
    sf.setOutputUnigrams(false);

    CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = sf.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    sf.reset();

    while (sf.incrementToken()) {
        System.out.println(charTermAttribute.toString());
    }

    sf.end();
    sf.close();
```

And get as expected 3 bigrams - this is, is a, a dog.